# App Store Connect Operation Error while uploading the archive to TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, testflight

Hi I'm trying to upload my app to TestFlight. I don't get any errors in archive process or build process but when I try to distribute my app to TestFlight I got an error. I tried to search it online but I couldnt find a solution. I don't know which part to share of my code. If you ask me I can share my code's necessary parts immediately
[image: error]

I tried to research for the error

Comment: It seems to mean that you are accessing non-public methods. Are you using a socket library?

Comment: What is socket library?

Comment: Where are you calling newsocketqueueforconnectionfromaddress?

Comment: Actually I don't. One library must be calling it. When I check the mail from apple, It was suggesting adding info.plist Apple Music usage permission description. After adding the description it worked